# My HTML is not working according to my code

Tags: html

Why my HTML is not working according to my code? See [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/q4cv6qdt/) here.

The output of the is

`F (textbox)`

`L (textbox)`

`button`

Right?. What I am doing wrong here?.

```
<div>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>F</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" style="width: 50px;" id="txtBS" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>L</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" style="width: 50px;" id="txtBSLName" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAlert">
    Add</button>
</tr>
```

Comment: your html is working as according to your code.what exactly is your question?

Comment: @BibekAryal and Soorapadman.. Below answers solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tr`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp) is not a valid child of `div`. Use [`table`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp) instead. As well as your button is missing a `td` as wrapper.

Note that layout with tables is usually not the way to go, unless you're actually displaying a table.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>F</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" style="width: 50px;" id="txtBS" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>L</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" style="width: 50px;" id="txtBSLName" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAlert">
                Add
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/q4cv6qdt/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You forget to add `<table>` tag

```html
<div>
<table>


    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>F</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" style="width: 50px;" id="txtBS" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>L</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" style="width: 50px;" id="txtBSLName" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAlert">
    Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```